# Android Fragment onCreateView has null ArrayList despite initialization

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a main activity with a ViewPager. I am trying to populate the ViewPager using an Adapter.

This is my Fragment Class.

```
public class ClassListFragment extends Fragment {

private List<item_timetable_class> _classList;

public ClassListFragment() {
}

public ClassListFragment SetClassList (List<item_timetable_class> classList) {
    ClassListFragment fragment = new ClassListFragment();
    fragment._classList = classList;
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // some code here

    //In this line I am getting _classList = Null        

      class_card_adapter adapter = new class_card_adapter(_classList, getContext());

    // some code here
    }

}
```

This is how I am calling the Fragment. Please note that Just after creating a new ClassListFragment Object, I am calling SetClassList so that the internal variable _classList is Set.

```
    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    for (int i = 0; i < weekday_list.size(); i++) {
        ClassListFragment newFragment = new ClassListFragment();
        newFragment.SetClassList(classCardList);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(newFragment, weekday_list.get(i));
        i++;
    }

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Unfortunately, the onCreateView method is being executed when the below line is being executed in the main activity.

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

And at that time, the List _classList is coming as null.

What could be the problem and How can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating `ClassListFragment`:

```
ClassListFragment newFragment = new ClassListFragment();
```

And then do not keep reference to fragment returned from `SetClassList`:

```
newFragment.SetClassList(classCardList);
```

Modify `SetClassList`:

```
public ClassListFragment SetClassList (List<item_timetable_class> classLis)
{
    _classList = classList;
    return this;
}
```

And keep reference to the returned `Fragment`:

```
newFragment = newFragment.SetClassList(classCardList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer: [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

(The correct way to do what you want is using `Bundle` and `Parcelable` objects into the Fragment arguments)

---

Anyway, you called two separate "constructors" here.

```
ClassListFragment newFragment = new ClassListFragment();
newFragment.SetClassList(classCardList);
```

`public ClassListFragment SetClassList` **returns** a `new ClassListFragment`, it does not set the current one.

---

Try this instead.

```
public static ClassListFragment newInstance(List<item_timetable_class> classList) {
    ClassListFragment fragment = new ClassListFragment();
    fragment._classList = classList;
    return fragment;
}
```

And

```
for (int i = 0; i < weekday_list.size(); i++) {
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(
        ClassListFragment.newInstance(classCardList), 
        weekday_list.get(i));
    // i++; // You already increment this in the loop...
}
```

Comment: Your answer is more informative! thanks, but R. Zagórski's answer involves least amount of code changes. Thanks, you all are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this:

```
    public static ClassListFragment newInstance(final List<item_time_table_class> classList) {
ClassListFragment fragment = new ClassListFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle()
args.putParcelable(key, classList);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

ClassListFragment::onCreate() {
classList = getArguments().getParcelable(key);
}
```